# php apache url redirect

Tags: php, apache, redirect

I need help with Apache redirect. I have pages like these

```
http://www.domain.com/1841-England-Census/County/Surname/Aa
http://www.domain.com/1851-England-Census/County/AA
http://www.domain.com/1861-England-Census/Surname/AA
```

I want those pages, ie anything under a subdirectory http://www.domain.com/????-England-Census/ to be redirected to following new URLs respectively without any querystrings added to the new URLs

```
http://www.domain.com/search/?Key=1841
http://www.domain.com/search/?Key=1851
http://www.domain.com/search/?Key=1861
```

Answer (score 0):

simply add
in php before any data is sent to screen

```html
/* Redirect browser */
header("Location: http://www.google.com");
```